# What is the stability order for these octahydrobiphenylene structures?

Tags: organic-chemistry, stability

According to me most stable is Z because it has maximum alpha hydrogen, 
Between X and Y both have same alpha hydrogen, but X has conjugation. So it is more stable than Y.

[image]

So Order is Z>X>Y. 
Is my explanation correct?

Comment: You are ignoring strain in a cyclobutene ring which has to count for something in stability.

Comment: Yes Sir Your Right, Can Please help me with what other factors I should Look For

Comment: This is all about ring strain, you do not need to look for ther factors

Comment: ...and the antiaromaticity of cyclobutadiene X. Stereochemistry would help. Y>Z>X